# Keeping DEV, UAT, and PROD environments in sync with ArcSDE for Oracle?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, enterprise-geodatabase, oracle-dbms

Recently, I was doing some development work against our DEV environment. It seems logical at the time. When nearly complete, and after much face palming, I found the DEV environment was way out of sync with PROD (and UAT). Field names were different, nullable was true in PROD but not dev, data types were different, etc. etc.

What tools and practices could / should we be using to keep our various environments synchronized?

For example, in a pure Microsoft .NET & SQL Server world, I would use Red Gate to sync the database structure and data between the three environments.

What are my options for keeping ESRI SDE / Oracle synchronized between environments?